# How to get value of given key in LinkedHashMap?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In a template I'm iterating through my `Set<Map>` (this is what `root.getDetails()` returns):

```
@for(detailed <- root.getDetails()) {
  @detailed.get("key")
}
```

Problem appears during compilation with message `value get is not a member of ?0`. Leaving `@detailed` alone prints `{ key=> blahblah }` so looks like the key I'm trying to retrieve does exists.

Any clue how may I get the value of given key in `@detailed` map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that printing out the map gives you:

```
{key=>blahblah}
```

rather than:

```
{key=blahblah}
```

suggests that you are dealing with a Scala map in your view template rather than a Java map. The following should therefore work for you:

```
@for(detailed <- root.getDetails) {
  @detailed("key")
}
```